# How does the tagging system work for post titles?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

[My post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63643866/11792577) has this title:

> How to pass arguments to custom composer script

And four tags: [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel), [composer-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composer-php), and [phpunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phpunit).

When I published it, I found that the HTML title had this text:

> php - How to pass arguments to custom composer script - Stack Overflow

Why did the tagging system choose [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) out of four tags?

How does it decide the priority? Tags have watcher counts and question counts. Is there a formula?

I've searched, only to find *[Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)*.